How to direct a user to reset their password in Amazon Cognito lambda function?
We are using a Cognito Lambda function to create an OTP challenge for a user as an alternate login method.
There is now a new requirement that changes this flow; i.e. when then the user successfully enters the OTP and still has not set his password yet, he should be redirected to the new password entry screen; (they do not have to enter the temporary password).
As a workaround I could just check if the temporary password is set in our DB and make an internal call to the enter password function and then just pass the reset password challengeSession back to the User. But I wanted to check if that was possible via the lambda function itself.
Here is the defineAuth function that I have modified;
import { SESClient, SendEmailCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-ses";
import crypto from "crypto";
import https from 'https';
import { CognitoIdentityProviderClient, AdminGetUserCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client- 
 cognito-identity-provider";

 const client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({});
 const ses = new SESClient({ region: "us-west-2" });

 const handler = async (event) => {
if (event.triggerSource === "DefineAuthChallenge_Authentication") {
    return defineAuth(event);
} else if (event.triggerSource === "CreateAuthChallenge_Authentication") {
    return createAuthChallenge(event);
} else if (event.triggerSource === "VerifyAuthChallengeResponse_Authentication") {
    return verifyAuth(event);
}
};

const defineAuth = async (event) => {
  const maxAttempts = 3;
  const sessionList = event.request.session;
  const sessionCount = sessionList.length;
  const latestSession = sessionList[sessionCount - 1];
  if (sessionCount == 0) {
      event.response.issueTokens = false;
      event.response.failAuthentication = false;
      event.response.challengeName = "CUSTOM_CHALLENGE";
  } else if (sessionCount <= maxAttempts && latestSession.challengeName == 
    "CUSTOM_CHALLENGE" && latestSession.challengeResult == true) {
      const userPoolId = event.userPoolId;
      const username = event.userName;
      let userStatus;
      try {
          const command = new AdminGetUserCommand({
              UserPoolId: userPoolId,
              Username: username
          });
          const response = await client.send(command);

          userStatus = response.UserStatus;
       } catch (error) {
          event.response.issueTokens = false;
          event.response.failAuthentication = true;
          return event;
      }
      if (userStatus == "FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD")
          event.response.challengeName = "NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED";
      else {
          event.response.issueTokens = true;
          event.response.failAuthentication = false;
      }
  } else if (sessionCount < maxAttempts && latestSession.challengeName == 
    "CUSTOM_CHALLENGE" && latestSession.challengeResult == false) {
      event.response.issueTokens = false;
      event.response.failAuthentication = false;
      event.response.challengeName = "CUSTOM_CHALLENGE";
  } else {
      event.response.issueTokens = false;
      event.response.failAuthentication = true;
  }

  return event;
 };

It fails in the try catch block now after I enter the correct OTP for a user with the error (Invalid session for the user.). I want to check the user status (if they are waiting to have their password changed then make the changes for initiating the NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED challenge. Is this functionality possible in cognito?
